# Can we use Yolo to detect and recognize text in a image

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, text-recognition

Currently I am using a deep learing model which is called "Yolov2" for object detection, and I want to use it to extract text and use save it in disk, but i don't know how to do that, if anyone know more about that, please advice me

I use Tensorflow

Thanks

Comment: Your model was trained for object detection but you want to use it to extract text? The two don't seem compatible. Can you explain in more detail what you want to do?

Comment: In fact what I want to do is to exctract object from images, and if some images are labels with special label "for example number plate", I want to take this object and extract the text that is display on it, how can I do that ?

Comment: hi @KamelBOUYACOUB did you try training images with bounding  box around word to detect similar written words(font wise) in test image. We also tried YOLO darknet to extract user handwritten written data from forms. for same user handritten data in test images . it is doing good if image has different color intensity but it was not good if images are rotated . We used pretrained darket weights with yolo.cfg model.  Please share your finding in this

Comment: @donald, could you please share more information on your work around extract handwritten text from forms?

Comment: @donald can u share text extraction from forms.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use the pretrained model, you would need to save those outputs and input the images into a character recognition network, if using neural net, or another approach.

What you are doing is "scene text recognition". You can check out the Reading Text in the Wild with Convolutional Neural Networks [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1842), here's a [demo](http://zeus.robots.ox.ac.uk/textsearch/#/search/) and [homepage](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/text/). Github user chongyangtao has a whole [list](https://github.com/chongyangtao/Awesome-Scene-Text-Recognition) of resources on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar question and I am making a digit detection model with svhn dataset. It is not a finished project yet, but it seems to work well. You can see the code at [Yolo-digit-detector](https://github.com/penny4860/Yolo-digit-detector).

Comment: S/O Review: @penny please try to explain your answer in detail. Simply posting links does not add value and is not allowed on S/O. I should probably flag this as "not an answer", but I think you may have some value to add to this, so I'd like to give you a chance to share it! Always try to be as comprehensive as possible and ensure that your answer actually contains the answer to the question. Examples of your code in action as related to the question would be hugely beneficial.